# ConfigurableNavigationHandler parameter issue

Tags: jsf-2

Trying to navigation from Page A to Page B. While navigating to page B passing parameter using configurableNavigationHandler like below

```
public void navigate(String outcome) {
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ConfigurableNavigationHandler nav = (ConfigurableNavigationHandler) fc
            .getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
    nav.performNavigation(outcome+"?faces-redirect=true&includeViewParams=true&oldPage=hello");
}
```

In Page B when I click on back it has to retrieve the parameter value and navigate the user to the respective page.But getting null value while retrieving the request parameter.

```
public String navigateToOldPage() {
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    String oldPage = fc.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("oldPage");
    return oldPage;     
}
```

Could anyone please suggest me?

Answer (score 0):

You're basically trying to access the `oldPage` parameter in the wrong HTTP request, namely the one of a form submit in page B instead of the one wherein page B itself is shown.

There are basically 2 options:

1. Set the request parameter as a bean property during displaying of page B using `<f:viewParam>`:

   ```
   <f:metadata>
       <f:viewParam name="oldPage" value="#{bean.oldPage}" />
   </f:viewParam>
   ```

   with (on a `@ViewScoped` bean)

   ```
   public String navigateToOldPage() {
       return oldPage;
   }
   ```

   ---
2. Retain the request parameter in the `UICommand` component responsible for the form submit using `<f:param>`:

   ```
   <h:commandButton ... action="#{bean.navigateToOldPage}">
       <f:param name="oldPage" value="#{param.oldPage}" />
   </h:commandButton>
   ```

   Or, if it just needs to be a real GET request, then use `<h:button>` (or `<h:link>`)

   ```
   <h:button ... outcome="#{param.oldPage}" />
   ```

Comment: Many thanks and sorry for the delayed response.I'm trying to make the navigation in generic way.I just wrote a controller class( a plain java class) and placed both the methods navigate and navigateToOldPage.In all the bean I will call this navigate method like below UIController.navigate("PageName"). Inside this navigate method getting the viewId from facesContext and adding as request parameter.This requires for back button functionality.Please suggest me if anything wrong?

Comment: Yes, I understood that you were trying something like that. Was the answer helpful or not?

Comment: Many thanks BalusC and sorry for the delayed response. The answer was partially helpful

Comment: It'd be helpful if you elaborate what problem exactly you're having. I couldn't understand it based on the 1st comment.